# Can you disable autosave in pycharm with a shortcut?

Tags: pycharm

I do a lot of live editing in the browser and have livereload. The autosave messes up my workflow when I have to transfer changes from my browser to my actual files. I want to keep autosave in the general case, but I want to toggle it at will.

Anyone know if that's possible? All hits on google is about turning it off completely and I'm hoping I'm missing some option from the keymap.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible, as describe on the [Saving and Reverting Changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html) help page.

However, if it is HTML, CSS and JavaScript you edit in the browser, then have a look at the [Live Editing of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html) support where you with a Chrome plugin can turn it around and as a result no longer need to manually copy changes done in the browser to PyCharm.